# Variadic template parameter expansion issue

Tags: c++, c++14

Below is a class (with a variadic function) declaration and definition in separate files(.hpp and .cpp). Using c++14.

```
// in header file

class NameBuilder{
public:
  NameBuilder();
  ~NameBuilder();

  template<typename T>
  T Stitch(T lLast);

  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  T Stitch(T lFirst, Args... lArgs);
};

// in .cpp file

NameBuilder::NameBuilder() {}
NameBuilder::~NameBuilder() {}

template<typename T>
T NameBuilder::Stitch(T lLast) {
  return lLast;
}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T NameBuilder::Stitch(T lFirst, Args... lArgs) {
  return lFirst + Stitch(lArgs...);
  }

template int NameBuilder::Stitch<int>(int);
template int NameBuilder::Stitch<int, int...>(int, int...);

// instantiation

  NameBuilder n;
  auto out = n.Stitch(1,2,3);
```

clang error says : Pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs, on this line `template int NameBuilder::Stitch<int, int...>(int, int...);`, and the program does not compile. Having spend some time trying to get my head around this I am stuck.
What is wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: It cannot work this way, because partial specialisations of function templates are not allowed.

Comment: If you want to do this, you'll need to explicitly declare _every_ instantiation you'll use: `<int, int>`, `<int, int, int>`, `<int, int, int, int>`, etc.  I would very much recommend just putting the definition of `Stitch` in your header.

Comment: @Miles I might end up using the header in multiple places in the project and am worried this may offend the ODR(rule).

Comment: Templates are implicitly `inline`, so as long as you don't have any different definition of the same function, it will be fine from ODR point of view.

Comment: Once you resolve this issue, I expect you'll have an "ambiguous call" error. Both overloads of `Stitch` can be called with one argument.